# How can I create repetitive form elements in a DRY way with Flask-WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a WTForms form where I want the user to be able to upload up to 10 images, and also give the images captions and credits. Currently I declare all 10 sets of fields, but this seems redundant. Is there a way to create form fields with dynamic names, so I could create them in a loop?

```
class MyForm(Form):
    image1 = FileField('Upload')
    image1_caption = StringField('Caption')
    image1_credit = StringField('Credit')
    image2 = FileField('Upload')
    image2_caption = StringField('Caption')
    image2_credit = StringField('Credit')
    # ...through 10 images...
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for WTForms [field enclosures](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#field-enclosures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get what you're looking for by combining [`FormField`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FormField) with [`FieldList`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList):

```
class ImageForm(Form):
    image = FileField('Upload')
    caption = StringField('Caption')
    credit = StringField('Credit')

class MyForm(Form):
    images = FieldList(FormField(ImageForm), min_entries=10)
```

You can then access the individual `ImageForm` instances either through `my_form_instance.images.entries` or by iterating over `my_form_instance.images`:

```
for image in my_form_instance.images:
    print(image.data['caption'], image.data['credit'])
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Good to know the terms I needed and how to use them.